# What is proper way to work with guava's striped in reactive programming?

Tags: java, kotlin, locking, reactive-programming, guava

How to work with guava's stiped class? 
For example, I have the following code:

```
return collector.collect(event)
    .flatMap { data -> handler.handle(obj.type(), data) }
```

event has field id. I have to lock next executions for specific id. How can I use stripes here? I cannot wrap it with try/catch block, also I cannot unlock it in `doOnNext` and `doOnError` blocks.

Comment: Any news on this?